# Disabling VLC's crash message

Tags: vlc-media-player, applescript

I have a Mac Mini running videos on loop to display publicly, which occasionally crashes I think generally when other OSX functions kicking in. I have a script to detect when VLC is not running and reboot it, but there is often a system message on top "VLC crashed previously".  Is there a way to disable this (I can find no option in VLC's advanced options), or perhaps to feed a 'Continue' response to it via Applescript?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a vlc error message, I believe instead it's Mac's usual Problem Reporter. In Snow Leopard, from a terminal, this command

```
sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/CoreServices/Problem\ Reporter.app
```

disables it, while this

```
sudo chmod 755 /System/Library/CoreServices/Problem\ Reporter.app
```

re-enables it. You did not specify your OS, but I hope you can use this as a starting point.

EDIT:

I did not say I didn't know how to disable the Crash Reporter, lol. I only said I did not know which OS you were on. ;-)

At any rate:

```
defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none
```

turns it off,

```
defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType crashreport
```

turns it back on. Only thing is: I cannot test it.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I'm Mountain Lion, which doesn't have the Problem folder, but this sounds like the right approach.